# paginator django

Tags: django

Возможно уже кто-то подобное делал, нужно средствами обычного django paginator сделать подобное (жирным выделена активная страница, остальные ссылки на страницы):

1 2 3 ... 7 8 **9** 10 11 ... 41 42 43
или
**1** 2 3 ... 41 42 43
или
1 2 **3** 4 5 ... 41 42 43

Comment: В доках есть все что вам нужно, я гарантирую это!

Answer (score 4):

Посоветую вам вместо `django`'вского использовать [django-pagination](https://github.com/ericflo/django-pagination/).
Легко подключить, и гибко настравается

в `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
       # ...
       'pagination',
   )
...
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
       # ...
       'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware',
   )
```

в шаблоне

```
#подключить тег
{% load pagination_tags %}
...
#разбить массив на страницы
{% autopaginate object_list 10 %}
...
#вывести пагинатор
{% paginate %}
```

Для кастомизации пагинатора вам надо перегрузить шаблон `templates/pagination/pagination.html`

```
{% if is_paginated %}
{% load i18n %}
<div class="pagination">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}{{ getvars }}{{ hashtag }}" class="prev">&lsaquo;&lsaquo; {% trans "previous" %}</a>
    {% else %}
        <span class="disabled prev">&lsaquo;&lsaquo; {% trans "previous" %}</span>
    {% endif %}
    {% for page in pages %}
        {% if page %}
            {% ifequal page page_obj.number %}
                <!-- Вот здесь в вашем случае выводится текущая страница -->
                <!-- можно добавить <b> или <strong> или попросту ничего не -->
                <!-- перегружать, а описать класс current -->
                <span class="current page">{{ page }}</span>
            {% else %}
                <a href="?page={{ page }}{{ getvars }}{{ hashtag }}" class="page">
                      {{ page }}</a>
            {% endifequal %}
        {% else %}
            ...
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}{{ getvars }}{{ hashtag }}" 
                 class="next">{% trans "next" %} &rsaquo;&rsaquo;</a>
    {% else %}
        <span class="disabled next">{% trans "next" %} &rsaquo;&rsaquo;</span>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Я не то имел в виду. Ваш метод не плох, но я умею с пагинаторами обращаться, у меня встроенный уже, однако как и вы написали простой << 3 из 47 >>. А я именно расстановку в шаблоне хотел подробную сделать. Просто думал задача популярная, думал кто-то уже расписывал.

Answer (score 0):

вот что вам нужно, с использованием foundation 5:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="large-3 large-offset-5 columns">
        <ul class="pagination">
            {% if articles.has_previous %}
                <li class="arrow"><a href="/page/{{ articles.previous_page_number }}/">&laquo;</a></li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="arrow unavailable"><a href="">&laquo;</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {% for page in articles.paginator.page_range %}
                {% if page == articles.number %}
                    <li class="current"><a href="/page/{{ page }}/">{{ page }}</a></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li><a href="/page/{{ page }}/">{{ page }}</a> </li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% if articles.has_next %}
                <li class="arrow"><a href="/page/{{ articles.next_page_number }}/">&raquo;</a></li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="arrow unavailable"><a href="">&raquo;</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня было подобное:

```
{% for page in p.page_range|p_filter %}
   {% if page == '...' %}
       {# ... #}
   {% elif page == request.GET.page %}
       {# current #}
   {% else %}
       {# other_page #}
{% endfor %}
```

templatetags.py

```
@register.filter()
def p_filter(page_page)
    Ваша логика обработки page_range :)
    return [1, 2, 3 , '...', 33, 34, 35]
```